# ExchangeWebServices attachment load

Tags: email-attachments, exchangewebservices, jscript

I'm using EWS with JScript (I know, not recommended, but I have no choice!)...

I can connect to my Exchange server, log in, retrieve messages, and identify a message with a file attachment. Now I want to save that attachment locally.

I have:

```
  for (x = 0; x < myMessages.Items.Count - 1; x++)
  {
    thisitem = myMessages.Items.get_Item(x);
    if (thisitem.HasAttachments)
    {
      attachment = thisitem.Attachments.get_Item(0)
      attachment.Load("c:\\temp.xls");
```

But this produces an error:

mscorlib

System.ArgumentException: Object of type "System.String" cannot be converted to type "System.IO.Stream"
....

I know the attachment is an XLS.... and it's something to do with the overloading of the Load method... But beyond that I'm lost.

Help?!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needing to do something like this, in the end I found this worked (this is Jscript in TestComplete - amend as you need to!):

```
  if (thisitem.HasAttachments)
  {
    for (y = 0; y < thisitem.Attachments.Count; y++)
    {
      var attachment = thisitem.Attachments.get_Item(y);
      if (attachment.get_IsInline() == false)
      {
        if (attachment.name.OleValue.indexOf(attachsuffix) == attachment.name.OleValue.length - attachsuffix.length)
        {
          attachment.Load();
          aqFileSystem.CreateFolder(targetfolder)
          var filename = targetfolder + attachment.Name.OleValue
          var fos = dotNET.System_IO.BinaryWriter.zctor(dotNET.System_IO.File.Open(filename, dotNET.System_IO.FileMode.Create))
          fos.write_3(attachment.content)
          fos.Close();
          Log.Message("Saved: " + filename);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```